# How To Reset Test Orders And Dashboard Statistics in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, dashboard, statistics

In Magento 1.x we can reset test orders and dashboard statistics by following [link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Admin-Configuration-Questions/How-To-Reset-Test-Orders-And-Dashboard-Statistics-Magento-1-9/m-p/29852#M1410). In Magento 2.x may different names when we compare Magento 1.x and Magento 2.x tables.

Any one having solution? to reset test orders and dashboard statistics in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

    # Clean order history
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;

    # Clean order infos
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;

    # Clean cart infos
    TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
    TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;

    # Reset indexes (if you want your orders number start back to 1
    TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_invoice_1;
    TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_order_1;
    TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_shipment_1;
    TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_creditmemo_1;


    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: its work for me after restart mysql

Answer (score 0):

Be safe : make a backup of your sql first.

Please run below SQL query

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

# Clean order history
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;

# Clean order infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;

# Clean cart infos
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;

# Reset indexes (if you want your orders number start back to 1
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_invoice_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_order_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_shipment_1;
TRUNCATE TABLE sequence_creditmemo_1;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```